# How to use a lamdba with Either in a map function?

Tags: haskell, lambda, either

What I try to do is the following:

```
map ((\Left x -> x + 1) [1, 2]
```

... and I would expect it to return

```
[2, 3]
```

However, I get the following error:

```
<interactive>:25:14: error: parse error on input ‘)’
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

You have incorrectly organized your parentheses, and introduced Either when it's not related to any of the other code.

Write

```
map (\ x -> x + 1) [1, 2]
```

It's not clear why you want Either to be involved, since you're mapping over a list without any Either values in it.  Maybe what you want is

```
map (\ (Left x) -> x + 1) [Left 1, Left 2]
```